# Change ID of record being displayed on record page

Tags: lightning, pagereference

When I am displaying a record page (such as `https://myorg.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Lead/00Q3i000004FudyEAC/view`), how could my component on that page change the record being displayed? I know I could just navigate to a page for a different object, but that would cause an entire page reload. I'm looking for an API such as `changePageRecordId`. My expectation would be that this would simply update `clientId` on all the components on the page, without reloading or redrawing it.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. Such an operation would certainly involve redrawing and reloading data in any case, since a server round-trip would be required and it might even necessitate rendering a different Lightning Page should the new record have a different Record Type.

Use the Lightning Navigation Service to request a move to a new record's page, in [Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) or [LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation).

Comment: Thanks. But it does not seem unreasonable, if the record type is the same, to ask for the flexipage to update itself (meaning all its constituent components) to a new recordId. I don't see why that should necessitate a page-level reload. For instance, let's say I want to have a navigation component to go up and down in some list of records, put that on the page, then the user clicks to move to the next or previous record, and all the record-specific components simply update themselves smoothly in place.